# Rails Tutorial 8.25

Tags: railstutorial.org

I am currently working through Rails Tutorial 4.0. I have reached completed everything up to 8.2.5. For the life of me I can't get a user to be able to sign-in. I have all my valid users specs failing and when I try in the browser, I always get username/password combination failure messages. I have inspected the params debug and the email and password I am using match what I set them to when signing up. The user exists in the database. The only thing I can think of is something with the encryption of the remember_token or something. Any help would be great

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name "James"
    email "test@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+).[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name  , presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :email , presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  before_save{ email.downcase! }
  before_create :create_remember_token
  has_secure_password

  def User.new_remember_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  def User.encrypt(token)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
  end

  private
  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = User.encrypt(User.new_remember_token)
  end
end
```

authentication_pages_specs

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Signin Page" do
    before { visit signin_path }
    it { should have_content('Sign In') }
    it { should have_title('Sign In') }
  end

  describe "Signing in" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    describe "invalid signin" do
      before { click_button "Sign In" }

      it { should have_title('Sign In') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error',
                                text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
        before { click_link "Home" }
        it { should_not have_select('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",        with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password",     with: user.password
        click_button "Sign In"
      end

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign Out', href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign In', href: signin_path) }
    end
  end
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<header class='navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse'>
  <div class='navbar-inner'>
    <div class='container'>
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class='nav pull-right'>
          <li><%= link_to "Home",    root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help",    help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li id = "fat-menu" class = "dropdown">
          <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
            Account<b class='caret'></b></a>
          <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
            <li><%= link_to 'Profile', current_user %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Settings', '#' %></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample Application!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Stepping away and coming back at another time works best. The problem I had was in the views/sessions/new.html.erb which seems like the only file I wasn't looking at at the time. I accidentally had the password label and password_field using symbol :Password instead of :password.